# Why only the phonon with $k=0$ contribute Raman intensity?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, crystals, phonons

I have read some literature to know that Raman intensity corresponds to the inelastic scattering of light with ion vibrations, and the positions of Raman peak correspond to the energy of phonon.

My question is on the large crystals such as large graphene, in which the phonon modes have wave number k. I found in many literature such as [10.1016/j.jssc.2011.02.009], only the gamma point phonon were considered, why? Is it a kind of approximation? And what is the physical reason behind the approximation.

Comment: Consider the momentum ($k$) of a phonon vs a photon.

Comment: Do you means the k of phonon should be identical to photon? But I found incident ray of Raman device was scattered to every angles, maybe the active phonon momentum is spreading over large range.

Answer (score -1):

In deficit k cohesion or adhesive or covalent bond structure non-chemically but harmonically through electronic microscopic or oscillation dissertive spacing analysis and readings should get you the dispersion rate and in which a pattern on how that particulars of the event may problematic to track in visual scales but pixels can be use through some bio scale in witch to germinate the hybrid specimen or mechanical further microscopic nanotech inclusion integrated along with macrobio with gna helix capability trip and quad helix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).